# force variable evaluation within Makefile

Tags: sed, makefile

In one of my Makefiles, a variable receives a value determined by a `sed` script :

```
VAR_SCRIPT:=`sed -n '/expression/s/.*[[:blank:]]\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' < file.h`
```

The `sed` script will find the appropriate value within `file.h`.
It works fine. Later on this value is used to create versioned file names.

But in fact, the `sed` program is not evaluated at the moment `VAR_SCRIPT` is created. It keeps its *script* format all along, and is only evaluated at the last moment.

This cause problems in later parts of the Makefile. Typically, I would like the result of `VAR_VALUE` later on in another `sed` script, not the script formula itself.

Trying to transfer the value of the `sed` script through :

```
VAR_VALUE := $(VAR_SCRIPT)
```

only transfers the script, not the result of the script.

How to force evaluation of the `sed` script ?

*Edit* : one solution found :

```
VAR_VALUE := $(shell echo $(VAR_SCRIPT))
```

See also @Andrey suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `shell` function:

```
VARIABLE := $(shell command)
```

For example, check this `Makefile` (no tabs):

```
C := sed -n 'p' <<< 'test'
V := $(shell $(C))
all: ; @echo $(V)
```

Comment: Tried multiple versions, none of them work. At best it doesn't crash and return 0.

Comment: Finally got it to work by using : 
`VAR_VALUE := $(shell echo $(VAR_SCRIPT))`

Comment: Maybe you don't need backticks. I added an example Makefile.